# Raspberry Pi Zero 2W - SSH causes a halt

Tags: ssh, pi-zero-w-2

I connect Raspberry Zero 2W via SSH to the computer and everything looks correct, but when I'm trying to install some library like `pip install mysql-connector-python` or run symfony command `symfony composer require symfony/orm-pack` LED on raspberry starts blinking from strong light to very weak light then SSH connection disconnects. When I  just connect the monitor to the Raspberry PI everything is fine.

I did such a test that in the same time I connected RPI to monitor (with terminal) and also I logged into SSH. When SSH connection disconnected I could still see the terminal on the monitor but when  I typed a command in terminal nothing happened, only the cursor blinked.

I tried to turn off power management `sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off` also I added IPQoS cs0 cs0 to /etc/ssh/sshd_config but problem still exist. Also I used 2 memory cards with new installed OS.

I use 5V 2A power supply.

Answer (score 0):

Check the system logs (/var/log/syslog, /var/log/messages, etc.) for any error messages or warnings that might indicate what's causing the issue. Also check if the power supply is actually supplying 5V,2A. If you are not using the official power supply, chances are high that the power supply is not working as expected.